# Change region of static web app to Europe

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

For GDPR compliance we want to change the region of our static web app to Europe or even better Germany.

There is no option to do so. On other SO questions I found the solution to create a new static web app and redeploy. But now when I create it with `region=westeurope` the newly created resource still has the location `Global`.

How to change the region of our web app to the EU or even better Germany?

Edit: The region is still Global but in the overview of the resource group it shows the right location. We redeployed the app and just manually copied the (luckily few) settings, still 4 hours of work..

Jahnavi's answer should work if you have the Premium plan. Unfortunately we migrated before we saw the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @Joel Odey. By referring to this [blog](https://ohekpejeodey.com/the-smart-way-to-move-your-web-app-resources-across-regions-in-azure) I found an approach using "Clone APP".

You can try this replica for your question with the following steps:

- Create another destination app service plan.
- Make sure you clone the app service into the same resource group and region as the destination plan.
- Search for the web app you want to clone.
- Inside the web app, click on `clone app` feature available on the left side of the blade.
- Select the new region while cloning the app and click on `clone`
- Delete the previous service plan.

[image]

Before cloning, the region is Central Us:
[image]

After cloning, I moved it to East US region:

[image]

**Note**: To perform cloning operation, you need to have premium app sevice plan otherwise it will not be possible.

For more info you can refer this [Ms Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-plan-manage#move-an-app-to-a-different-region)